# PHP mixing up <?php <% underscore template

Tags: php, underscore.js, wordpress

I use underscorejs template system in one of my wordpress plugin, but one of the user send me this message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in /wp-content/plugins/dnui-delete-not-used-image-wordpress/html/backup.php on line 13

After doing some search, i came to the conclusion that php is interpreting the `<%` like `<?php` and trying to run the code, but the code is in js/template underscore

```
<% var src; %>
```

Any of you have any idea of why is this? how to fix it? I try to search how to change the

```
<?php
```

for another type but only got the answer of

```
<?
```

Comment: Disable this: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags

Comment: What do you mean " php is taking the <% like"? As in it's converting `<?php` to `<%`, or it's using asp tags by default? Also `var src;` doesn't look like valid PHP, is that part of underscorejs?

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv i was trying to find this information in the php documentation, but is seen that i didn't do a good search.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑyes the <% if for making templates with javascript in the client site, but after the first comment this is probably the problem, php take the <% like <?php and is trying to run the code like php, but is javascript, well thank any way

Answer (score 0):

If you used wp.template for your templates you can find your answer [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.template)

if you use underscore template directly in your js file you should change template setting like this :

```
    /*
     * Underscore's default ERB-style templates are incompatible with PHP
     * when asp_tags is enabled, so your template uses Mustache-inspired templating syntax.
     *
     * Make the underscore template like wp.template function
     *
     */
    var templateSettings = {
        evaluate    :  /<#([\s\S]+?)#>/g,
        interpolate : /\{\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}\}/g,
        escape      : /\{\{([^\}]+?)\}\}(?!\})/g,
        variable    : 'data'
    };

    var innerGizmoTemplate = '<div class="{{ data.className }}">'
    + ' <# _.each( data.params, function( param ){ #>'
    + ' <div class="karma-builder-gizmo-{{ param.type }} {{ param.className }} ">'
    + ' <# if( "icon" === param.type ){ #>'
    + ' <div>{{{ param.icon }}}</div>'
    + '<# } else if( "text" === param.type ) {#>'
    + '<div>{{{ param.value }}}</div>'
    + '<# } #>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<# }) #>'
    + '</div>' ;

// then get it easily like this
var compiled =  _.template( innerGizmoTemplate, templateSettings );
console.log( compiled( YourParams ) );
```